# Acknowledgment on ZMQ

Tags: load-balancing, pyzmq

I'm building a real-time service using Python, by the Master - Slave architecture, such that each service is on a DIFFERENT server.

The communication between the services is done using [ZMQ](https://zeromq.org/).

**Problem:**

Slave requests something from Master. Master responds. I need the slave to respond back again to the Master (on the master's response, like a signature) - simple acknowledgement or a different response.
Is there any simple way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :** *"  Is there any simple way to do so ? "*

**A :**
Yes, there is.

Use another `PUSH/PULL`-signalling path from Slaves to Master and handle signalling messages according to your needs.